# My question (seemingly) unfairly reflects on two products, how should I resolve?

Tags: discussion

I posed a question [Why can't the Docker ("master") container see workers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35723630/why-cant-docker-master-container-see-workers) and I'm now concluding that my problems arose from misconfiguring Linux.

The question may make Docker and CitusDB look bad because it mentions both.  Citus
wants to fix it but I may not have time to sanitize my scripts.

Recommendations?  Should I post an answer and mark 'answered'?

Comment: you could just delete it, but answering it works too if you can answer it in a way that would be useful to other users.

Comment: What do you mean by "Citus wants to fix it"?

Comment: That question looks like it should be posted rather at [SE ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) or [SE SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). I can't spot a _specific programming problem_.

Comment: A Citus engineer replied to the question asking for my config and scripts so he could determine if this was a repeatable problem and if so, fix it.  I think we just had a misconfigured machine.  I can't really send him files without reviewing such files for sensitive information (like what a cool scripter I am, I suppose).

Comment: It's off topic, so just delete it.